# Laravel join with sub query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models User and Address, one user can have many addresses but I want to fetch only which is `primary(where primary=true)`

this is what I have tried, and I am getting multiple users in the list

```
$users = User::join('addresses', 'addresses.user_id', 'users.id')
             ->select('name','phone_number','address','landmark','city','state','pincode','users.status')
             ->get();
```

I tried this too but I am not getting any data

```
$users = User::join('addresses', 'addresses.user_id', 'users.id')
             ->where('addresses.primary', true)
             ->select('name','phone_number','address','landmark','city','state','pincode','users.status')
             ->get();
```

thank you

```
Collection {#375 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => User {#376 ▶}
    1 => User {#377 ▼
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "name" => "Colin Sushanth"
        "phone_number" => "9987217545"
        "address" => "2nd Cross 3rd street, y this is my address"
        "landmark" => "Near the address"
        "city" => "Mangalore"
        "state" => "Karnataka"
        "pincode" => 575002
        "status" => "valid"
        "primary" => "true"
      ]
    }
    2 => User {#378 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Let's start from this: why do you use `join` and not just Eloquent relationships?

Comment: Not getting the point of primary(where primary=true)

Comment: @AddWeb Solution i have a column named primary in `addresses` i want to get the address of the user only which is primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$users = User::join('addresses', 'addresses.user_id', 'users.id')
             ->where('addresses.primary','=',1)
             ->select('name','phone_number','address','landmark','city','state','pincode','users.status')
             ->get();
```

Or:

```
$users = User::join('addresses', 'addresses.user_id', 'users.id')
                 ->where('addresses.primary','=',true)
                 ->select('name','phone_number','address','landmark','city','state','pincode','users.status')
                 ->get();
```

### Updated answer

Blade file:

```
@if(isset($users))

  @foreach($users as $user)

    @if($user->primary === 'true')

        //Your code

    @endif

  @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: thanks for your time really appreciate it, the `primary` field won't be `NULL` it will be either `true` or `false`, and i want to get the address which is `primary=ture`

Comment: @MrRobot Ok let me check it

Comment: I have set enum for primary field as `(true/false)` so I tried your second solution, i am not getting any error but i am not getting any data. thank you

Comment: @MrRobot Try with whereHas('addresses.primary') may be work

Comment: @MrRobot Not sure but at least try

Comment: getting an error `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, string given, called in D:\Workspace\Project Ideal\idealchicken\app\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php on line 13 and defined`

Comment: @MrRobot Ohh sorry leave it

Comment: @MrRobot I think we can restrict primary in blade also

Comment: how do i do that, if it is that would be great

Comment: @MrRobot First remove ->where('addresses.primary','=',true) from query

Comment: @MrRobot Then dd($users) display result set

Comment: @MrRobot Please check my Updated Answer

Comment: well that worked, thank you really appreciate your time

Comment: @MrRobot Glad to help and Welcome any time

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using eloquent models

So you would u do

```
User::whereHas('primary')->pluck('name','phone_number','address','landmark','city','state','pincode','users.status')
```

and your model will look like this

```
 public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Address');
    }

    public function primary()
    {
        return $this->addresses->primary == true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response, tried your solution i am getting an exception 
`(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: which object and what is your address model called? if you have one?

Comment: my bad, it was a typo, now i have a different one `Property [primary] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: probably need to put a get() or a all() on the where method